# How is this cumulative distribution formed?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a probability density function that equals $f(x)=\begin{cases}.1\quad \text{for $0\le x\lt 2$}\\.2\quad \text{for $2\le x \lt 4.5$}\\.3\quad \text{for $4.5\le x\lt5.5$}\\ 0\quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and I'm wondering how the cumulative distribution function is formed. I have the solution, but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The cumulative distribution function $F$ can be obtained from the density function by integration:
$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(u)\, du.$$
Thus, $F$ is piecewise linear with slope $0.1$ on $[0, 2)$, slope $0.2$ on $[2, 4.5)$, slope $0.3$ on $[4.5, 5.5)$, and slope $0$ otherwise ($F(x) = 0$ for $x<0$ and $F(x) = 1$ for $x \geq 5.5$).